# Latex code required for drawing geodesic space

Tags: programming

I want to draw that particular picture in $\LaTeX$ but does not getting the point how to make code in latex kindly give some suggestion:

[image]

Comment: You might find more help at [TeX stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). My guess is you'll probably want to use a package like tikz.

Answer (score 0):

For you and all others who want to create nice diagrams, I recommend this book: [An Illustrated Theory of Numbers.](https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/) I have tried out the LaTeX packages and plan to use this from now on.